# Проблема с сравнением паролей php

Tags: php, mysql

В моей базе пароли зашифрованы в md5. И когда хочу залогиниться, то пишет "Incomplete combination of password and login". Не могу понять в чём ошибка, надеюсь на вашу помощь!

```
    public function connexion()
{
    switch ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
        case 'GET' :
            if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
                $error_message = "You are already connected as " . $_SESSION['user'];
                include 'views/error.php';
            } else {
                include 'views/connexion.html';
            }
            break;

        case 'POST' :
            if (isset($_POST['login']) && isset($_POST['pw'])) {
                $login = htmlspecialchars($_POST['login']);
                $pw = htmlspecialchars($_POST['pw']);
                $u = User::get_by_login($login);
                if (!is_null($u)) {
                    if ($u->getMdp() == hash('md5', $pw)) {
                        $_SESSION['user'] = $login;
                        $_SESSION['uid'] = $u->getId();
                        $_SESSION['usadmin'] = $u->getIsAdmin();
                        header('Location: index.php?ctrl=video&action=showVideos');
                        exit();
                    } else {
                        $error_message = "Incomplete combination of password and login";
                        include 'views/error.php';
                    }
                } else {
                    $error_message = "This login does not exist !";
                    include 'views/error.php';
                }
            } else {
                $error_message = "Incomplete fields !";
                include 'views/error.php';
            }
            break;
    }
}


public function getMdp()
{
    return $this->_mdp;
}

public function setMdp($pw)
{
    if (is_string($pw)) {
        $this->_mdp = $pw;
    } else {
        $this->_mdp = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: md5 в настоящее время практически не представляет никакой безопасности, 80-90% паролей из 20000 расшифровываются за час с правильным словарем и правилами составления

Answer (score 0):

У вас метод getMdp возвращает пустое значение, т.к. не вижу, где setMdp устанавливает значение переменной $this->_mdp (которая используется для сравнения). И подозреваю, что в setMdp($pw) поступает пароль, а не его хэш, после чего вы сравниваете пароль с хэшом, что не будет равно.

И как верно заметил @etki, не используйте md5, либо хотя бы солите пароли.